# ERROR ITMS-90283: "Invalid Provisioning Profile" in Mac-Catalyst app

Tags: macos, mac-catalyst

I'm working on a Mac-Catalyst app. It needs to access some of the AppKit Classes so I integrated a macOS Bundle to accomplish that(reference blog post: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-access-the-appkit-api-from-mac-catalyst-apps-2184527020b5), and it works fine except it won't let me upload the app to the Appstore. When I try to upload the app XCode throws me an error:

ERROR ITMS-90283: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.XXX.MacPlugin [com.XXX.XXXX.pkg/Payload/XXX.app/Contents/PlugIns/MacPlugin.bundle] is invalid. [Invalid 'com.apple.application-identifier' entitlement value.] For more information, visit the macOS Developer Portal."

I tried uploading the build removing this plugin and it worked, but with this Plugin it won't work.